# Make the width of the dropdown list equal to their parent

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I want to put a button and a dropdown list side by side, so I have to use `display: inline-block`. Then I realise it is difficult to make the width of the dropdown list equal to their parent (ie, `Version`); the method like `position: relative` and `width:100%` does not work.

Does anyone know how to do it?

[JSBin](https://jsbin.com/duqujalura/2/edit?html,output)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    dropdown {
      position: relative
    }
    dropdown-menu {
      width: 100%
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="border-top-right-radius: 0px;border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;">
    Save</button><div class="dropdown" style="display:inline-block">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" style="border-top-left-radius: 0px; border-bottom-left-radius: 0px">Version
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li ng-repeat = "x in versions">
        <a href="#">{{x}}</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <script>
    var app = angular.module('app', []);
    app.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
      $scope.versions = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    }])
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am confused by your question. Are you asking how to make the dropdown the same width as the button (`Version`) or are you asking how to make the menu items appear horizontally by the button ("side by side")?

Comment: make the dropdown the same width as the button `Version`. I mention `Save` in the question, because I am afraid `display: inline-block` that I have to use complicates the issue...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In bootstrap, `.dropdown-menu` has a `min-width` value. Override this:

```
.dropdown-menu {
  min-width: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

[demo](https://jsbin.com/cosuxitizo/1/edit?html,css,output)